# error_perm: 500 Unknown command Python ftplib storbinary

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm trying to upload a file using ftplib in Python.

```
ftp = FTP('...')
ftp.login('user', 'pass')                   
f = open(filename)
ftp.storbinary(filename, f)
f.close()
ftp.quit()
```

storbinary is returning `error_perm: 500 Unknown command.`, which is strange since I'm following its specification. Google search returns very little information. Anyone encountered this problem ?

Comment: What is `filename`? Does it have path info, e.g., slashes, in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're using [`storbinary`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) incorrectly. You want to pass `"STOR filename-at-location", f)` to send the file. Does this work?

```
ftp = FTP('...')
ftp.login('user', 'pass')
with open(filename) as contents:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % filename, contents)
ftp.quit()
```

Comment: filename is the name of the file a I want to upload which is at the current location

Comment: Ok, but if the filename doesn't have any slashes in it, that means you're trying to upload to the root directory you are logging into. Is that your intent?